# Fragment which implements Observer pattern

Tags: android, fragment, observer-pattern

I have a maybe little bit stupid question, but I didn't find any answers on this. So I have a Fragment and some entity object which extends Observable. I want my Fragment to be notified when some changes were made in my entity, so I implemented an Observer there.

Now I have some doubts about where observers have to be added and deleted. I mean the most correct callbacks in fragment.

Now I'm using `onViewCreated` to add observer, `onDestroyView` to delete observer, but I think that there are may be better places to do it.

Here is a sample code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    WheelManager.getInstance().addObserver(this);
    PreferenceManager.getInstance().addObserver(this);
}

@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        WheelManager.getInstance().deleteObserver(this);
        PreferenceManager.getInstance().deleteObserver(this);
    }
```

I will be very thankful for answers.

**UPD:** Also I've looked through [Official Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html), but find nothing about this question.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the updates?

Comment: Displaying some updated values in fragment views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said you're just updating views, onCreateView and onDestroyView are suitable places for this code.

There is an exception to this and that's when you're updating AdapterViews and RecyclerViews -- you can instantiate your adapter in onAttach and start observing from there (and stop it in onDetach). You can link your adapter to your view in onCreateView and never worry about NPE's etc.

Comment: Ok, so seems like onCreateView and onDestroyView are best places to add/delete observer.